# Was my question closed properly?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I have asked a question here [How to write function in point free style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391699/how-to-write-function-in-point-free-style?noredirect=1#)

This question was put on hold. I asked in comments for a reason with reference to concrete rule I broke, but I didn't get clear answer.

Could you please explain to me what exact rule I broke?

Comment: I think it can be broad, but not too broad :) And people who answered, understood that question correctly and gave correct answers.

Comment: @chepner's comment is probably most relevant.  The Haskell experts just can't understand why you want to solve this problem.  The question has no clue why you need to.  You can probably get some random "this is another way to do it" answers and "look over here" comments, but the odds that this is actually helpful advice to anybody else, and you, easily get low.  Closing it prevents more random answers.

Comment: We basically ask for effort in questions. You say it's not an assignment... I'll trust you there. But can you see how it looks like something copy and pasted from an exam/homewo k assignment, by a student who just wants the answer without searching for it?  Do remember Stack exists for the future. Not just you, but all the other users looking for a solution to the same problem. That's why we like more generic 'I tried X. Expected Z. Got Y... What did I misunderstand about X and Z?'

Comment: I will say though Will Ness' comment saying your code could be nonsensical isn't good. Your effort and attempt at solving should show your understanding and ideally showcase some research effort. I don't think posting garbage code to 'check the checkbox' does that

Comment: @Patrice ugh, you've misread my comment. What I said was: post your code attempt, even if it seems nonsensical. But the code you see in the question is not OP's attempt at solving their problem, it is a *statement of the problem* itself. -- Oops, I've misread your comment! :) I mean, let's say a person tries something, can see it's wrong but can't find the correct way. why not post it and ask for directions? that's what I meant.

Comment: @HansPassant " The Haskell experts just can't understand why you want to solve this problem." I disagree. This is a common thing to want to do, in Haskell. (that's why there were answers posted there, too). The problem as I saw it, is that the whole question consists of a problem statement only. There's nothing else there.

Comment: Sure, having experts disagree about what the question asks or tries to pursue is just yet another easily induced problem with such a question.  Gets out of hand badly sometimes when they start arguing with each other about it.  Well, in other tags, I trust that everybody is nice to each other in [haskell] ;)

Comment: First, for me your question could be improve by following the [ask] guideline. A paragraphe explain what the function will do. A clear definition of the "paradigm" you want to rewrite your function. And finaly the code block. perhaps a statement like code golf specifying how you judge an answer.

Comment: "What have you tried?" was a way to ask for the specific code that generate the issue. 
It's not about effort or handing answer in a silver plate. 
Imo here op ask for retranscription of a working code using an other method. Link the "in a more pythonic way" or "using linq question". 
One comes with a working clear piece of code and by curiosity want to see the equivalent.

Comment: I'm not saying it's ok because other tag have same question. 
I'm saying that the usefullness of the rewrite/the question doesnt make something off topics.
There are good-useless question that ask about how to write something. 
That get new answers every time the language add some syntax sugar. 
like for collection initialisation or dictionary etc. 

But closing a working code for MCVE is weird.

Comment: Question reached -10 but answer sums at 14+ before the delete.

Comment: @DragandDrop I've edited my question. Does it match your expectations now?

Comment: @WillNess I do get the distinction here.... I don't think that it is what the "easy" interpretation of that comment was.... but I can see the distinction.

Comment: @Patrice Saying "incorrect" or "incomplete" would've probably been better. :)

Answer (score 14):

I'm not one of the closers and neither do I use [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) or moderate it. However, at a quick glance:

1. It looks like the standard variation of a homework / assignment / quiz requirement dump.
2. You don't give any of your attempt(s) or any further information, just the code that you have now.
3. You are inviting many different answers by asking such an open ended question therefore this question would fall under being too broad (this is the closing reason I personally would have given).

If you take a look through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, you'll see your question falls inline with the "bad" questions. For example, in the tour there is a big heading which says:

> Get answers to practical, detailed questions

Ask yourself, '*Is my question practical?*'

It then further states the sort of questions you shouldn't ask about:

> Don't ask about...
>
> - **Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)**
> - Product or service recommendations or comparisons
> - **Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.**
> - Anything not directly related to writing computer programs

(emphasis mine)

Your question falls under 2/4 reasons.

I'm sure there are other reasons and only the closers can comment on *why* they voted the way they did, but this answer is simply based on an unbiased outsiders view.

Comment: there's no "*the* closer" there, but rather five of them. :) --- "dump" that's the heart of the matter, at least for me. As I wrote to OP in the comments there, otherwise I wouldn't have voted to close. -- "the code that you have now." no, that's not OP's problem-solving attempt's code, it's *a statement of the problem*.

Comment: @WillNess I honestly read '*the closer*' earlier and considered changing it but never (thinking back, I don't know why). Updated now anyway, thanks.

Comment: " 'Is my question practical?' " yes, it is, in the context of Haskell. It's just that the entire question consists of a problem statement. (I'm reiterating this, because as you've stated you're not a Haskeller, and it might superficially seem otherwise). -- "Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)" that's it! thanks for finding it. Now the OP have their answer.

Comment: @WillNess fair enough and I appreciate the insights, thanks once again.

Comment: I'd say reasons #1 and #2 apply, but not #3 -- "rewrite this Haskell function in pointfree style" is a fairly narrow requirement. (FWIW, I saw this question on the [haskell] feed and chose not to cast a close vote, but I get why the other folks did so.)